# Twitter Composer Callback OnSuccess/OnFailure Fabric

Tags: java, android, twitter-fabric

I am trying to detect whether the tweet was successful or not. How can this be achieved on Android using the Fabric (Twitter Composer) api?

```
new TweetComposer.Builder(activity)
                                .text("#hastag").show();
```

What I want to do:

```
new TweetComposer.Builder(activity)
                                .text("#hastag").
                                .onSuccess(new Success(....))
                                .onFailure(new Failure(...)
                                .show();
```

I could listen to the onActivityResult method in the Activity but I was hoping there would be a cleaner and better way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of using `.show();` , create an intent like this :

```
new Intent i = new TweetComposer.Builder(activity)
                                .text("#hastag").
                                .createIntent();
```

Now you can start the activity for result :

```
startActivityForResult(i, TWEETER_REQ_CODE);
```

where `TWEETER_REQ_CODE` is just a numerical identifier.
next `onActivityResult` wait for the `TWEETER_REQ_CODE` to show up.

Hope it helped,
N.

Comment: But it giving when the view of twitter starts on after when user creating post successfully and how to close that view ? If you have done this kindly post here. Thanks. @ntcase

Comment: onActivityResult is gettign triggered even when i discard the post....? how to handle the failure part ?

Comment: Above solution work for me thank you ntcase & shevski

Comment: @Priya did you found any answer to your comment? I am stuck in a similar situation.